# Finding nearest neighbors within a distance and taking the average of those neighbors using cKDTree

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, point-clouds

I'm using python scripting to read in two large (millions of points) point clouds as arrays ("A" and "B").

I need to find the nearest "B" neighbors of the points in "A", but within 5 cm of each point in "A". I also want to average the neighbors within the 5 cm radius of the points in "A."

Is there a way to do this using cKTree all at once, including the averaging?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what do you want to do, but If I understand you correctly you can follow this steps:

```
# this are just random arrays for test
A = 20 * np.random.rand(1000, 3)
B = 20 * np.random.rand(1000, 3)
```

#### Compute a cKDTree for each point cloud

```
tree_A = cKDTree(A)
tree_B = cKDTree(B)
```

#### Find the points in A that are at most at 5 units from each point in B:

```
# faster than loop + query_ball_point
neighbourhood = tree_B.query_ball_tree(tree_A, 5)
```

#### Compute the mean over all of those groups of points:

```
means = np.zeros_like(A)
for i in range(len(neighbourhood)):
    means[i] = A[neighbourhood[i]].mean(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

cKDTree does not have any units; I'm hopeful that your measurements are all in the the units (cm) as your desired manipulations.

What do you mean that you want to "average the neighbors"?  Is this simply the mean location of all the neighbors within the 5-unit ball?

From what you've posted, I believe that the critical operation for you is

```
for A_point in A:
    hood = B.query_ball_point(A_point, 5)
```

Now, just "average" the points in **hood**.  I assume that you know how to do that part; cKDTree doesn't have such an operation, since SciPy and Python supply those on the base types.

You could do this with **A** as the first argument to **query_ball_point**, but then you'd get a *huge* list of neighbourhoods, and perhaps blow your memory limit.

Does that get you moving?